# Pass a URL argument with render_to_response

Tags: django, django-forms

i use this code to views.py file

```
@login_required
def login_edit_page(request):
#bla bla
return render_to_response('login_edit_page.html', variables)
```

the problem is that when the return is called, i have to also pass an argument from the URL. for example the URL is /edit?id=1 in this example i want to pass the id. how can i do that?

this is the full code

```
@login_required
def login_edit_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginEditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login1 = _login_edit(request, form, request.GET['id'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                                        '/user/%s/' % request.user.username
                                        )
    id2 = request.GET['id']
    name=''
    url=''
    Login_username =''
    notes= ''
    password=''
    try:
        login1 = login.objects.get(
                                   id = id2,
                                   username=request.user
                                  )
        name = login1.name
        url = login1.loginUrl
        Login_username = login1.login_username
        notes = login1.notes
        password = login1.password
    except (login.DoesNotExist):
        pass
    form = LoginEditForm({
                          'name': name,
                          'url': url,
                          'Login_username': Login_username,
                          'notes': notes,
                          'password': password
                        })
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
                                        'form': form
                                        })
    login1 = _login_edit(request, form, id2)
    return render_to_response('login_edit_page.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) the way you do. Try this:

```
...
id2 = request.GET.get('id', None)
...
ctx = {
    'form': form,
    'id': id2
}
return render_to_response('login_edit_page.html', ctx,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Note, that I added `id2` to context dict, so it is reachable in the template by `{{ id }}`. Also, checkout how I retrieve url parameter from request.

Another approach is to reach url parameter directly from `request` (as Mark Lavin noticed, it will work in case of `django.core.context_processors.request` is present in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`):

```
{{ request.GET.id }}
```

But sincerely, you should make your view more clean, there are a lot of problems in it.

Comment: The last approach assumes `django.core.context_processors.request` is enabled in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` but it is not included by default.

Comment: i  tried your solution but still getting "Exception Value: "Key 'id' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"http://pastebin.com/M23qRRdC

Comment: @Dimitris, take a look at line 7 of code snippet you provided. You are still using this invalid approach of getting url parameter. Use `request.GET.get('id', None)` instead. It is all because request is not a common python dict, but object of `QueryDict`

Comment: it seems that id doesn't pass correctly again to _login_edit because i get an "login matching query does not exist." exception that comes from _login_edit. In this pastebin i included also the _login_edit http://pastebin.com/zZLkt1ca

Comment: This is not related to the question. You should read [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) to improve your basic django and python skills.